# Unable to hide button and then un-hide it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a loading screen which has an animated activity indicator and label that displays "Loading". All created using Interface Building. This screen is displayed to the user until my RSS feed has finished parsing.

If the device does not have an internet connection the activity indicator is removed from the view, a reload button is displayed in its place and the labels text is changed to "Reload"

```
@synthesize loadingView, loadingIndicator, loadingLabel;

BOOL isFirstOffersLoad = YES;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (isFirstOffersLoad) [self parseFeed];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navigation"]];
}

- (void)parseFeed
{
[self.loadingIndicator startAnimating];
self.loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

NetworkStatus networkStatus = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus];
if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Unavailable" message:@"More Cobalt requires an Internet connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    self.loadingLabel.text = @"Reload";
    self.loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
    self.reloadButton.hidden = NO;
}
else {
    // Download and parse XML data
    [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
    isFirstOffersLoad = NO;
}
}

- (IBAction)reload:(id)sender {
    [self parseFeed];
}
```

However when you tap the reload button I would like the button to hide, the activity indicator to reappear and the label's text to change to "Loading" again. Like it does when you first launch the app.

Can someone out there help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since your reload method responds to the button press, just add the desired changes:

```
- (IBAction)reload:(id)sender {
    [self parseFeed];

    self.loadingLabel.text = @"Loading";
    [self.loadingIndicator startAnimating];
    self.reloadButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi Teddy, that seems to half fix the problem, however if the internet is not available and I would expect the reload button to show again. Using the code above just shows the activity indicator and the loading label.